# eBay Product scraper

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am very limited on VBA,

The Code is in a Module, the code has a sub process as well, so sorry if I post the code wrong

- A) open IE
- B) Subprocess gets the data.

---

1. The code works fine on ebay.com but NOT for ebay.co.uk - can't work out why, also it converts urls to hyperlinks
2. It only does the first page, I need it to go through an X amount of pages -  have a code but can't get it to work so have removed it.
3. Can the search query be run AFTER Ebay opens, so it opens, then search item is input to ebay and then code runs, or to run from a cell, IF its Cell A1 the data extracted needs to be pasted in A2 and below.

---

1. I have looked at elements for ebay.com and ebay.co.uk and they look the same to me, so can't work out why its not working as it works for 1 and not the other.
2. I did input the code for getting data from several pages it did not work. I know this code works as I have it for when I fetch urls from google

---

```
Public IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Sub GetData()

    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTml.HTMLDocument
    Dim othwb As Variant
    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            '.Navigate "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=jackets&_sacat=0"
            .Navigate "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html_from=R40&_nkw=ralph+lauren&_sacat=1059&LH_TitleDesc=0&_dmd=1&rt=nc"
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
                ProcessHTMLPage HTMLdoc

            .Quit
        End With


End Sub
code here

    enter 

'''''' THIS IS THE SUB PROCESS '''''


Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTml.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLItem As MSHTml.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLItems As MSHTml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTml.IHTMLElement
    Dim rownum As Long

    rownum = 1

    Set HTMLItems = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("s-item__title")

    For Each HTMLItem In HTMLItems

            Cells(rownum, 1).Value = HTMLItem.innerText
            rownum = rownum + 1

    Next HTMLItem

    rownum = 1

    Set HTMLItems = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("s-item__price")

    For Each HTMLItem In HTMLItems

            Cells(rownum, 2).Value = HTMLItem.innerText
            rownum = rownum + 1

    Next HTMLItem

    rownum = 1

  Set HTMLItems = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("s-item__link")
    For Each HTMLItem In HTMLItems
             Cells(rownum, 3).Value = HTMLItem.href
            rownum = rownum + 1

    Next HTMLItem

'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink from C1 to 25000 rows
  Range("C1:C25000").Select
    For Each xCell In Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell
Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```

Code for going to next page

```
pageNumber = 1
'i = 2
    If pageNumber >= 6 Then Exit Do 'the first 6 pages
    internetdata.getElementById("pnnext").click 'next web page
    Do While internet.Busy Or internet.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set internetdata = internet.document
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
Loop
```

1. Does not work on Ebay.co.uk -  NO RESULTS ARE EXTRACTED - Works fine in ebay.com
2. Need it to get data from X amount of pages and NOT just 1 page
3. Can the search query be run AFTER Ebay opens, so it opens, then search item is input to ebay and then code runs, or to run from a cell, IF its Cell A1 the data extracted needs to be pasted in A2 and below.

This is my code for google search, I have got it working so the search comes from cell A1, I am look for something like this, I am going to see if I can use the ebay code with this. As this also does the first 25 pages in google search

```
enter Sub webpage()

Dim ie As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nextPageElement As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim i As Long

' Takes seach from A1 and places it into google
url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, " ", "+")


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate url
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With


Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

Set htmlDoc = ie.document


pageNumber = 1
i = 2
Do
    For Each div In htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If div.getAttribute("class") = "r" Then
            Set link = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            Cells(i, 2).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next div
    If pageNumber >= 25 Then Exit Do 'the first 25 pages
    Set nextPageElement = htmlDoc.getElementById("pnnext")
    If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do

    ' Clicks web next page
    nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Set htmlDoc = ie.document
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
Loop


MsgBox "All Done"

Set ie = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set nextPageElement = Nothing
Set div = Nothing
Set link = Nothing
```

End Sub
code here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is less of programming question and is more of a freelance job.

Comment: Please convert this into separately posted questions. Resolve question 1 here first - why is it working for one site and not the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1: Why does it work for one domain but not the other?**

To answer question 1 (the other questions should be new posts) - the html is not the same at all. The classes which work for ebay.com are not found in ebay.co.uk; So, your loop over collections doesn't do anything because they are count 0 (or length 0 with nodeLists if using querySelectorAll). Instead, you need branched code. Set your selectors based on the url domain.

I have used css selectors as this is the easiest, and fastest way, to select the required elements whilst maintaining the flexibility of a code re-factor to reduce the lines of repeated code.

---

**Side note:**

If you are unsure about whether your selection method will work across different pages you can do at least two things:

1. Right click > inspect element > visually check the class names are the same for the elements you are attempting to compare. So, if you are looking at product names, are the class names in the html the same on both pages?
2. You can use the search facility of the browser > open element tab via <kbd>F12</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to pull up search box > enter your class name from the first page into this box in the second page and hit enter. You can also enter css selectors here and some cases regex. You will get a hit count telling you how many matches found. You can keep pressing enter to cycle through matches and each match will be highlighted in the html above, so you can easily compare if matched results are what you expected.

<sub>**click image to enlarge**</sub>

[image]

img url:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWkEx.png

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        '.Navigate2 "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=jackets&_sacat=0"
        .Navigate2 "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html_from=R40&_nkw=ralph+lauren&_sacat=1059&LH_TitleDesc=0&_dmd=1&rt=nc"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim index As Long, HTMLItems As Object, rowNum As Long, xCell As Range
        Dim cssSelectors(), i As Long

        Select Case True
        Case InStr(.document.URL, "ebay.co.uk") > 0
            cssSelectors = Array(".gvtitle a", ".amt", ".gvtitle a")
        Case InStr(.document.URL, "ebay.com") > 0
            cssSelectors = Array(".s-item__title", ".s-item__price", ".s-item__link")
        End Select

        With ws
            For i = LBound(cssSelectors) To UBound(cssSelectors)
                rowNum = 1
                Set HTMLItems = ie.document.querySelectorAll(cssSelectors(i))

                For index = 0 To HTMLItems.length - 1
                    .Cells(rowNum, i + 1).Value = IIf(i = 2, HTMLItems.item(index).getAttribute("href"), HTMLItems.item(index).innerText)
                    rowNum = rowNum + 1
                Next
            Next
            For Each xCell In .Range("C1:C25000") '<= all these really?
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
            Next xCell
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this works on eBay then you need to find out yourself why it's not working on ebay.co.uk. My point is if the code itself works than there is nothing we can help you with here. You need to take some time to investigate ebay.co.uk and find the differences as I am sure it's something minor. I can't help u fix code that isn't actually broken. I wish you luck though.

Comment: It's ok I have worked out what the problems with .co.uk and .com is. It was all the same today and for the past few weeks, I haev gone in again and checked and all the elements class have changed. I have mad the changes and it has started to pull in data